# Proving an Isomorphism via Generators

Tags: group-theory, group-isomorphism, group-presentation

> Prove that it is sufficient to map the generators and their relationship onto each other in order to show that we have an Isomorophism between two Groups.

Say we have $\langle g,h\mid g^3=1,h^2=1,hg=g^{-1}h\rangle $ and $\langle a,b\mid a^3=1,b^2=1,ba=a^{-1}b \rangle $. It is very obvious to me that there must be an Isomorphism because it simply means that it is esentially the same group but just with different symbols. If we let $\phi(g)=a$ and $\phi(h)=b$ this should get me an Isomorphism. But abstractly an Isomorphism means that $\phi(xy)=\phi(x)\phi(y)$ and this is by no means obvious.

Comment: so if generators go to generators then we have an iso? sorry, just for my own understanding.

Comment: yes and with the relations together. Is this generally speaking wrong and only in specific situations the case?

Comment: no, I believe you are correct, isomorphisms send generators to generators

Comment: The wording  of the question is so imprecise that it is difficult to say what it means exactly. (But in your example the groups  are indeed obviously isomorphic, because they you have just changed the labelling.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.

Use [Tietze transformations](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tietze_transformations) (and their implicit isomorphisms) to introduce new generators equal to existing ones, rewrite relators/relations using those generators, and then to delete the old ones.

For example,

$$\begin{align}
\langle g,h\mid g^3=1,h^2=1,hg=g^{-1}h\rangle &\cong \langle g,h, a\mid a=g, g^3=1,h^2=1,hg=g^{-1}h\rangle\\
&\cong\langle h, a, b\mid b=h, a^3=1,h^2=1,ha=a^{-1}h\rangle\\
&\cong\langle a,b\mid a^3=1,b^2=1,ba=a^{-1}b\rangle.
\end{align}$$